# Does Java compiler optimize stream filtering?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Let's have a case:

```
x.stream().filter(X::isFlag).filter(this::isOtherFlag).reduce(...)
```

Does it differ from this one?

```
x.stream().filter(predicate(X::isFlag).and(this::isOtherFlag)).reduce(...)
```

Comment: You can check by running `javap -c <class>`, if piped to a file _(`javap -c StreamTest > out.txt`)_, you can compare them easily

Comment: The Java "compiler" (as in javac, the program) does not optimize this. However, the library may indeed collapse compatible steps in a Stream, see [the detailed description of the different types of operations and how they interact](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps)

Comment: You can always look at the source code to see how it keeps track of filters but nowhere in Javadoc it says that the implementation will stay the same or if it will optimize in any way.

Comment: I don't think they are different performance wise to begin with. Not until I see benchmark test results.

Comment: Thanks, @javier-martín, so actually, such cases may be optimized in runtime, correct?

Comment: @omickron it may, as in, the description in the implementation allows it in certain cases. However, it is not *mandated* - as other people told you, you can take a peek at the source of the runtime library.

Comment: About optimize different things in Java take a look to https://raygun.com/blog/java-performance-optimization-tips/

Comment: Given sufficient amounts of inlining they probably end up doing the same. In practice the first one is probably a tiny bit easier on the JITs since that's one less object allocation to optimize away. but i'm just speculating. In the end you need to measure or look at the assembly output.

Comment: @the8472 the saved object allocation has to be compensated within the stream implementation one way or another. In either case, there must be an encapsulated piece of code evaluating both predicates. It would be different when using a single `.filter(x -> x.isFlag() && isOtherFlag(x))`, however. Then, you have a slight headstart on the JIT side…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Functionally, the two statements are equivalent.  However, consider the two following blocks of code and their respective bytecodes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = List.of("Seven", "Eight", "Nine");

    list.stream().filter(s -> s.length() >= 5)
                 .filter(s -> s.contains("n"))
                 .forEach(System.out::println);
}

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
Code:
   0: ldc           #16                 // String Seven
   2: ldc           #18                 // String Eight
   4: ldc           #20                 // String Nine
   6: invokestatic  #22                 // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.of:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/List;
   9: astore_1
  10: aload_1
  11: invokeinterface #28,  1           // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.stream:()Ljava/util/stream/Stream;
  16: invokedynamic #35,  0             // InvokeDynamic #0:test:()Ljava/util/function/Predicate;
  21: invokeinterface #36,  2           // InterfaceMethod java/util/stream/Stream.filter:(Ljava/util/function/Predicate;)Ljava/util/stream/Stream;
  26: invokedynamic #42,  0             // InvokeDynamic #1:test:()Ljava/util/function/Predicate;
  31: invokeinterface #36,  2           // InterfaceMethod java/util/stream/Stream.filter:(Ljava/util/function/Predicate;)Ljava/util/stream/Stream;
  36: getstatic     #43                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  39: invokedynamic #52,  0             // InvokeDynamic #2:accept:(Ljava/io/PrintStream;)Ljava/util/function/Consumer;
  44: invokeinterface #53,  2           // InterfaceMethod java/util/stream/Stream.forEach:(Ljava/util/function/Consumer;)V
  49: return
```

-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = List.of("Seven", "Eight", "Nine");

    list.stream().filter(s -> s.length() >= 5 && s.contains("n"))
                 .forEach(System.out::println);
}

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
Code:
   0: ldc           #16                 // String Seven
   2: ldc           #18                 // String Eight
   4: ldc           #20                 // String Nine
   6: invokestatic  #22                 // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.of:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/List;
   9: astore_1
  10: aload_1
  11: invokeinterface #28,  1           // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.stream:()Ljava/util/stream/Stream;
  16: invokedynamic #35,  0             // InvokeDynamic #0:test:()Ljava/util/function/Predicate;
  21: invokeinterface #36,  2           // InterfaceMethod java/util/stream/Stream.filter:(Ljava/util/function/Predicate;)Ljava/util/stream/Stream;
  26: getstatic     #42                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  29: invokedynamic #51,  0             // InvokeDynamic #1:accept:(Ljava/io/PrintStream;)Ljava/util/function/Consumer;
  34: invokeinterface #52,  2           // InterfaceMethod java/util/stream/Stream.forEach:(Ljava/util/function/Consumer;)V
  39: return
```

We can see that, in the second example, one call to `invokedynamic` and `invokeinterface` are missing (which makes sense as we omitted a call to `filter`).  I'm sure someone could assist with me with the static analysis of this bytecode (I can post verbose files if needed), but the Java compiler clearly treats the single call to `filter` as a single `Predicate<String>` rather than splitting it at the operator `&&`, shortening the bytecode slightly.