# Performance of "filter()" method in Stream API in java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I wanted to know if the stream API of java handle both condition the same way or different? If its going to execute an independent loop for each filter, then in terms of performance there is a significate difference I think. How do you think it is?

Here are the two conditions

```
 1. filter(cond1 && cond2 && cond3)
 2. filter(cond1).filter(cond2).filter(cond3)
```

Example

```java
List<Employee> emps1 = employees.stream()                                                     
        .filter((Employee e) -> e.name.endsWith("n") && e.salary > 10000 && e.id % 2 == 1)    
        .collect(Collectors.toList());                                                        
                                                                                              
List<Employee> emps2 = employees.stream()                                                     
        .filter(e -> e.name.endsWith("n"))                                                    
        .filter(e -> e.salary > 10000)                                                        
        .filter(e -> e.id % 2 == 1)                                                           
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Reading the options, the first one will apply the condition concatenated with "ands" to the whole data, the others will apply cond1 to the whole, and the others to a reduced set each. My suggestion for you is to measure yourself with the data you have - I guess they will present differences even if you swap conditions order.

Comment: TLDR: Compiler handles it differently. We can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48513110/1285923. They did the analysis at the bytecode level of how the compiler handles it. For performance, IMO, it will not be significantly difference, the only optimization is in the operator short circuit.

Comment: code it on what is easier to read, and the second one seems like the way to do it. performance wise, there will be close to no diff

Comment: Any performance question can only truly be answered with benchmarking. Hypotheticals only go so far. I suggest you benchmark the code and find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of `filter(cond1 && cond2 && cond3)`, the processing of condition stops as soon as any of the conditions evaluates to `false` e.g. if `cond1` evaluates to `false`, the other conditions (`cond2` and `cond3`) won't be processed. Similarly, if `cond1` evaluates to `true`, the processing will proceed to the evaluation of `cond2` and if this evaluates to `false`, the condition, `cond3` will not be evaluated.

The processing of `filter(cond1).filter(cond2).filter(cond3)` too happens in the same manner, as can be seen from the following example:

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.of("one", "two", "three", "four")
        .filter(s -> {
            System.out.println("Hello");
            return s.contains("t");
        })
        .filter(s -> {
            System.out.println("Hi");
            return s.contains("f");
        })
        .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello
Hello
Hi
Hello
Hi
Hello
```

Thus, it does not make any difference and it's a matter of choice. The second one looks cleaner.

---

**Note:** For more complex expressions, you can use [`Predicate#and`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#and-java.util.function.Predicate-) which gives you two more benefits:

1. You can reuse the behaviour implemented by the `Predicate` with other streams in your code.
2. Further clean code.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Predicate<String> containsT = s -> s.contains("t");
        Predicate<String> containsE = s -> s.contains("e");
        
        Stream.of("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten")
                .filter(containsT.and(containsE))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
three
eight
ten
```

However, it doesn't make any difference in the way the processing happens.

Comment: "In the case of filter(cond1).filter(cond2).filter(cond3), all the conditions will always be evaluated." - got a source for that? I don't believe that's universally true, if at all.

Comment: I know how stream processing works, but the idea that all filters get executed for every element is just wrong; if they don't pass the first filter, consecutive ones don't get evaluated. https://ideone.com/yjOS8u